# Prove that $a^2b(a-b)+b^2c(b-c)+c^2a(c-a)\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b$ and $c$ be the lengths of the sides of a triangle. Prove that  $a^2b(a-b)+b^2c(b-c)+c^2a(c-a)\ge 0$. Determine when equality occurs.

We know that if $a,b,c $ are the sides of a triangle then we can let $a=x+y$,$b=y+z$,$c=z+x$. After that I put the values of $a,b,c$ in the given expression and I found  $2(xy^3+yz^3+zx^3)-2(x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2)$. So my target is to prove this expression is greater equal to $0$

Comment: You can use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for this

Answer (score 1):

HINT: divide by $$xyz>0$$ and write
$$\frac{x^2}{z}+\frac{y^2}{x}+\frac{z^2}{y}\geq x+y+z$$

Comment: Are you sure? I think there is mistake in your computations.

Comment: hello Michal, do you meant me?

Comment: Yes. Your dividing was wrong.